# How to solve error: connect() failed: Address family not supported by protocol family

Tags: c, http, sockets

When I put `./client www.google.com 80` into the terminal, I get the error:

> connect() failed: Address family not supported by protocol family

Here is my code. The issue seems to be with the `getAddressInfo` function.

```
#include <stdio.h> /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket(), connect(), send(), and recv() */
#include <arpa/inet.h> /* for sockaddr_in and inet_addr() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for atoi() and exit() */
#include <string.h> /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h> /* for close() */
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define RCVBUFSIZE 32 /* Size of receive buffer */

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage); /* Error handling function */

int getAddressInfo(const char* host, unsigned short* port) {
    struct addrinfo hints = {0};
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    struct addrinfo* result;
    int ret = getaddrinfo(host, "http", &hints, &result);
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo() failed: %s\n", gai_strerror(ret));
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in* sock_addr = (struct sockaddr_in*)result->ai_addr;
    char* servIP = inet_ntoa(sock_addr->sin_addr);

    *port = ntohs(sock_addr->sin_port);

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sock; /* Socket descriptor */
    struct sockaddr_in httpServAddr; /* HTTP server address */
    unsigned short httpServPort; /* HTTP server port */
    /* Server IP address (dotted quad) */
    char *httpRequest = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                        "Host: www.example.com\r\n"
                        "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"; /* HTTP request to send to the server */
    char httpBuffer[RCVBUFSIZE]; /* Buffer for HTTP response */
    int bytesRcvd, totalBytesRcvd; /* Bytes read in single recv() and total bytes read */

    if (argc < 2 || argc > 3) { /* Test for correct number of arguments */
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <Server IP> [<HTTP Port>]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    const char* host = argv[1];

    if (getAddressInfo(host, &httpServPort) != 0) {
        DieWithError("Failed to get server address information");
    }

    if (argc == 3) {
        httpServPort = atoi(argv[2]); /* Use given port, if any */
    } else {
        httpServPort = 80; /* Default HTTP port */
    }

    /* Create a reliable, stream socket using TCP */
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) {
        DieWithError("socket() failed");
    }

    /* Construct the server address structure */
    memset(&httpServAddr, 0, sizeof(httpServAddr)); /* Zero out structure */
    httpServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; /* Internet address family */
    httpServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host); /* Server IP address */
    httpServAddr.sin_port = htons(httpServPort); /* Server port */

    /* Establish the connection to the HTTP server */
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &httpServAddr, sizeof(httpServAddr)) < 0) {
        DieWithError("connect() failed");
    }

    /* Send the HTTP request to the server */
    if (send(sock, httpRequest, strlen(httpRequest), 0) != strlen(httpRequest)) {
        DieWithError("send() sent a different number of bytes than expected");
    }

    /* Receive the HTTP response from the server */
    totalBytesRcvd = 0;
    printf("Received: "); /* Setup to print the HTTP response */

    while ((bytesRcvd = recv(sock, httpBuffer, RCVBUFSIZE - 1, 0)) > 0) {
        totalBytesRcvd += bytesRcvd;
        httpBuffer[bytesRcvd] = '\0';
        printf("%s", httpBuffer);
    }

    if (bytesRcvd < 0) {
        DieWithError("recv() failed");
    }

    printf("\n"); /* Print a final linefeed */

    close(sock);
    exit(0);
}
/*
void calcRTT(char* host, char* servport, int trials) {

    struct addrinfo* servinfo = buildAddrInfo(url, port);
    int i;
    float sum = 0;
    for(i=0; i < trials; i++) {

        struct timeval start;
        struct timeval end;

    }


}

long timediff(struct timeval t1, struct timeval t2) {
    long elapsed = t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec;
    return elapsed * 1000;
}
 */


void DieWithError(char *errorMessage) {
    perror(errorMessage);
    exit(1);
}
```

I want to display the information of the URL I put into the terminal.

Comment: `httpServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host)` - inet_addr expects an IP address, not a domain name. Instead of ignoring most of the result you get from `getaddrinfo` you should instead use the `sock_addr` you get from there for connection.

Comment: Also, not all servers use `index.html`, so you should `GET /` instead. Also, you need to send the user-specified `host` in the request's `Host` header, don't hard-code it as `www.example.com`